# Configuración y Optimización de ImageMagick y Tesseract

Tags: linux, ocr

Estamos utilizando ImageMagick y Tesseract para tratar de leer la información de documentos, pero no estamos encontrando la configuración correcta y la combinación de ambos softwares para otimizar el documento tiff original escaneado y aplicarle a este la transformación con Tesseract para obtener un pdf con la información.

Primero digitalizamos el documento en un escaner con la configuración de 300 dpi, y el documento produce un tiff de unos 170kb.

Luego intentamos ejectuar un pre-proceso de la imagen con ImageMagick antes de pasarlo a Tesseract 3.0.3 para producir un PDF con el texto.

El primer comando que utilizamos es el siguiente:

```
 convert page.tiff -respect-parenthesis  -compress LZW -density 300  \
-bordercolor black -border 1 -fuzz 1% -trim +repage -fill white -draw \
"color 0,0 floodfill" -alpha off -shave 1x1 -bordercolor black -border 2 \
-fill white -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -alpha off -shave 0x1 -fuzz 1% \
-deskew 40 +repage  temp.tiff
```

Y luego aplicamos el Tesseract de esta manera:

```
tesseract -l spa temp.tiff temp pdf
```

Esto produce un pdf muy pesado (900kb, ejemplo en el enlace), pero Tesseract no es capaz de leer datos que están en celdas o justo debajo de encabezados sombreados.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3CPIZ_TyzFXd2UtWldfajR4SVU

Luego hemos intentado usar este comando:

```
convert page.tiff -compress LZW -fuzz 1% -trim -alpha off -shave 1x1 temp.tiff
```

Este produce un pdf más ligero (130kb, ejemplo en el enlace), pero todavía estamos teniendo los mismos problemas.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3CPIZ_TyzFXWFEwT3JucDBTVVU

¿Podría alguien indicarnos que camino seguir para optimizar la imagen para tratar de obtener información como los ejemplos? ¿O directrices para optimizar las imágenes para mejorar la precisión de Tesseract?

El tipo de documentos que estamos tratando de procesar son muy diferentes con diferentes tipos de letra y tamaños.

--Añadido--
Incluyo aquí el script que ejecutamos para transformar una imagen tiff. Lo tenemos montado en una máquina con ubuntu donde tenemos instalado ImageMagick y Tesseract. Para transformar el tiff llamamos al script pasandole el nombre de la imagen y el nombre de salida del pdf.

Ejemplo: `./transformTesseractOCR.sh nombre-del-tiff.tiff nombre-del-pdf`

```
#!/bin/bash

#Obtenemos el numero de paginas del archivo tiff
PAGES=$(identify -format "%n" $1)
FILE="${2%%.*}"
BUCLE=$(($PAGES-1))
cadena=""
declare -a array_temp_tiff
declare -a array_temo_pdf

# funcion que devuelve un nombre de 24 caracteres aleatorios + fecha + temp
get_random_name(){
    now=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
    random=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 24 | head -n 1)
    new_temp="temp-$random-$now"
    echo $new_temp
}

#Para cada pagina del archivo tiff, la procesamos con ImageMagick y transformamos con Tesseract en PDF
for i in `seq 0 $BUCLE`; do

    #Declaramos los arrays donde guardaremos los nombres de los archivos temporales
    declare -a array_temp_tiff
    declare -a array_temp_pdf

    #Generamos un nombre aleatorio para los archivos temporales
    read temp_pdf <<<$(get_random_name; echo)
    read temp_tiff <<<$(get_random_name; echo)

    temp_tiff="$temp_tiff.tiff"

    #Guardamos los nombres en los arrays
    array_temp_pdf[$i]="$temp_pdf.pdf"
    array_temp_tiff[$i]=$temp_tiff

    #Primero aplicamos la mejora del tiff con ImageMagick
    convert $1\[$(($i))\] -compress LZW -fuzz 1% -trim -alpha off -shave 1x1 $temp_tiff
    #convert $1\[$(($i))\]  -respect-parenthesis  -compress LZW -density 300 -bordercolor black -border 1 -fuzz 1% -trim +repage -fill white -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -alpha off -shave 1x1 -bordercolor black -border 2 -fill white  -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -alpha off -shave 0x1 -fuzz 1% -deskew 40 +repage  page$i.tiff

    #Ahora aplicamos el tesseract
    /usr/bin/tesseract -l spa $temp_tiff $temp_pdf pdf
done

#Creamos una cadena formada por todos los archivos pdf temporales creados anteriormente para juntarlos en un solo pdf
for element in "${array_temp_pdf[@]}"
do
    cadena+="$element "
done

#Juntamos los pdf temporales en un solo pdf
/usr/bin/pdftk $cadena cat output $FILE.pdf

#Borramos archivos pdf temporales
for element in "${array_temp_pdf[@]}"
do
    rm $element
done

#Borramos archivos tiff temporales
for element in "${array_temp_tiff[@]}"
do  
    rm $element
done
```

Comment: Interesante cuestión. ¿Sería posible que ofrecieras un [mcve] para que podamos replicar el comportamiento?

Comment: He añadido el código del script que ejecutamos para transformar un tiff. Para ello es necesario tener instalado ImageMagic y Tesseract 3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Un posible problema que veo es que los "grises" de los sombreados de las celdas de títulos, se transforman en "ruido", una cantidad de puntos negros para simular un "gris" en la imagen monocroma. Eso sin duda hace que no se puedan leer estos títulos y posiblemente los campos debajo, que al estar tan cerca de los mismos hacen que el OCR se "confunda" y no detecte el patrón de texto, la diferencia se nota con los datos del "concepto" que se encuentran algo más alejados de los sombreados y los reconoce bastante mejor.

Lo ideal, si lo que se busca es únicamente extraer el texto, es partir de una imagen más "limpia". Para lograr esto, ya sea desde el Scanner (si es éste el que entrega el tiff monocromo) o en un paso posterior si se recibe una imagen en escala de grises o color, lo que se debe hacer es encontrar un "nivel" de corte que determine qué cosas se transforman en puntos negros y cuales en puntos blancos. Este parámetro, muchas veces se puede configurar desde el brillo o contraste del Scanner, por software se pueden aplicar algoritmos similares, la idea es convertir lo "sombreado" en blanco, pero esto sobre una imagen en escala de grises o color, con el tiff de enlace ya no podemos hacer nada. Encontrar este nivel óptimo es algo muy artesanal y basado en el prueba y error, podemos ajustar un nivel adecuado para quitar el sombreado pero como contraparte eventualmente se podría estar eliminando información importante, tenemos además el problema que dicho nivel puede ser bueno para un tipo de documento pero malo para otro.

Un comentario aparte, hace algo más de 15 años me tocó trabajar bastante tiempo con scanners de alto volumen de Kodak, en ese entonces, nuestra experiencia de aplicar OCR sobre documentos heterogéneos no había sido muy buena, incluso usando motores avanzados de ese entonces, en general el OCR podíamos llegar a usarlo en documentos del mismo tipo y aplicado a "máscaras" o sectores puntuales de los mismos, para obtener algún que otro dato relevante.

Suerte..//